# Strange behavior of ConstraintLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I'm using the latest version of constraint layout (1.0.2) and I have encountered this kind of issue (screenshot below):
[image: Issue]

As you can see layout has been cropped from the bottom. This problem arises only in ScrollView or when I'm trying to use ConstraintLayout as item in RecyclerView:

[image: Bug in recycler view]

In both examples ConstraintLayout has layout_height as wrap_content(first because of ScrollView, second - I just need it). I have tried `android:fillViewport="true"`in ScrollView, but it's not working. How can I fix this issue?

Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/widget_toolbar"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_edit_profile_avatar"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_avatar"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_photo_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_photo_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_edit_profile_avatar"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_name_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_name_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_photo_label"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edit_profile_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_name_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_name_label"
                tools:text="Name"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_username_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/all_username_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edit_profile_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_correct"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_username_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_username_label"
                tools:text="Username"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_username"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_bio_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_bio_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_bio"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_bio"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edit_profile_bio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:capitalize="sentences"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                tools:text="Bioa lnmgkjn \n gkdnfmk.g .kfm kfmn mmhh lkm hklgk mngk \n nmgk mnkgnmh kjgnmh kgjnm hkgnm"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_bio"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/block_car_add_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                    android:text="@string/add_car_location"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_car_location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_76sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_arrow"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorStroke"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_currency_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_currency_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/block_car_add_location"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edit_profile_currency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:ems="12"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:text="@string/all_currency_usd"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_currency_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_currency_label"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_currency"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_mileage_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_mileage_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_edit_profile_mileage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:prompt="@string/all_mileage_km"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_mileage_label"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_mileage_label"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_edit_profile_mileage"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                    android:text="@string/edit_profile_change_pass_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_arrow"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorStroke"/>
            </FrameLayout>


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_password">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                    android:text="@string/edit_profile_change_logout_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_arrow"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorStroke"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_details_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_details_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_logout"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_email_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/all_email_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_email"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_email"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edit_profile_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_details_label"
                tools:text="some@mail.com"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_email"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_phone_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/all_phone_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_phone"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_phone"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_edit_profile_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="17"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_email"
                tools:text="+38 066 249 52 76"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorStroke"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_edit_profile_phone"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_remove_acc_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile_remove_acc_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view8"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_edit_profile_delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:width="@dimen/_64sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_gray_stroked"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_bold"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/_64sdp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="@string/all_delete_but"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_remove_acc_label"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_edit_profile_remove_acc_label"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your XML code would be helful

Comment: @Dipalis. added

Comment: I have found the issue. It's occurs when enter several lines in EditText(bio). But how can I fix this?

Comment: Chain `EditText` and bottom `view`

Comment: @Dipalis. I have used Vertical chain and views moves to top of layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Button` bottom is constraint with bottom of `TextView`. Which is further matched with the bottom of `View android:id="@+id/view8"`. But your View's bottom is not matched with the bottom. I had the same issue inside recyclerview where last child's bottom was not matched with parent Constraintlayout. Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_edit_profile_remove_acc_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font_regular"
    android:text="@string/edit_profile_remove_acc_label"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Best of luck :D

Comment: Thank you, but with your xml I got this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lxN_mdsMc_X9zGvjvR-ny_U4MqLNAcQk

Comment: @Skullper sorry my mistake. i didn't noticed the structure of your design correctly its your last textview ('tv_edit_profile_remove_acc_label') who's bottom should be matched with the parent. And set height to "0dp". If you want you can give bottom margin to the button as cherry on top of cake :)

Comment: It's almost helped, but my button and text connected as "align vertical centers" that's why I cannot set bottom constraint of the button to parent. And after setting height to 0dp text_view became the same height as button, but in my case TextView should have bigger height then button. I will trying another constraints

Comment: well my point was to set last child's bottom with the parent so that you wont get unusual behaviour of constraint layout you can try different heights and you can also try constraintVertical_bias (values between 0.0 to 1.0) to arrange your button or anything else vertically.

Comment: Ok, thank you. You helped me to understand my problem. I'll mark this as correct answer